# Is it possible to access attr_reader variables like an array in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class AwsAssets
    attr_reader :AWS_INSTANCE, :AWS_INSTANCE_RESERVATION, :AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONE

    @@AWS_INSTANCE = 1
    @@AWS_INSTANCE_RESERVATION = 2
    @@AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONE = 3
end
```

I'm trying to access these variable ID's in another file.  I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
def index
    types = AwsAssets.attr_reader
    @filter = "model_type_id NOT IN (#{types.join(', ')})"
end
```

This is obviously not correct syntax, I'm just wondering if I can access all the `attr_reader` variables somehow - I realize I could just put all of the attributes into an array, but there are like 100 variables that I would have to duplicate, which I would rather not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you mixed couple of different properties that you can define on a class, so I am not sure which one you want to use.

You can use class instance variables

```
class AwsAssets
  @AWS_INSTANCE = 1
  @AWS_INSTANCE_RESERVATION = 2
  @AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONE = 3
end

AwsAssets.instance_variables
# => [:@AWS_INSTANCE, :@AWS_INSTANCE_RESERVATION, :@AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONE]
AwsAssets.instance_variable_get "@AWS_INSTANCE"
# => 1
```

Or you can use class variables

```
class AwsAssets
  @@AWS_INSTANCE = 1
  @@AWS_INSTANCE_RESERVATION = 2
  @@AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONE = 3
end

AwsAssets.class_variables
# [:@@AWS_INSTANCE, :@@AWS_INSTANCE_RESERVATION, :@@AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONE]
AwsAssets.class_variable_get "@@AWS_INSTANCE""
# => 1
```

When you create class variable with @@, you will have the same value for this class and all subclasses. If you use class instance variables with @ you can have different values for parent class and subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Some meta-programming could be helpful for you here.

```
class AwsAssets
    # define your attributes here in a constant which is accessible from other classes
    ATTRIBUTES = [:AWS_INSTANCE, :AWS_INSTANCE_RESERVATION, :AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONE]

    # use the definition above to call `attr_reader` for each attribute in the array
    ATTRIBUTES.each { |attribute| attr_reader(attribute) }
    # OR a shortcut: attr_reader(*ATTRIBUTES)
end

def index
    # You can now access that array of attributes in other areas like so
    types = AwsAssets.ATTRIBUTES
    @filter = "model_type_id NOT IN (#{types.join(', ')})"
end
```

Here's a good resource for some more examples and information about meta-programming in Ruby: [Introduction to Ruby Meta-Programming Techniques](https://github.com/adevadeh/intro_meta_ruby)